# Preloading session variables and db interaction code igniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I'm preloading the sessions library in code igniter as my site needs a few sessions vars on most pages. I need to do the following, but don't know what the best way is to do this (ie: where to put the code):

1. check if a cookie is set
2. if a cookie is set, call the database to get the session data for a user (ie: user account settings)

do I need to add this kind of stuff on __ construct for Ci_Session or is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i suggest you using hooks: check the [Codeigniter Hooks](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)

i use to make session controls away from controllers, and hooks are a step foward you can run hooks pre or post system and controllers runtimes